# Gem usage: cocoon + selectize-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem, selectize.js

I can't make `selectize-rails` work with `cocoon`. (When adding +1 attendance selectize is not active for it). I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070190/ruby-on-rails-selectize-js-with-cocoon) question, but it brought me nowhere.

What I have:

```
- Attendance model
- Event model
- Event has_many :attendances
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.selectize')){
        $('.selectize').selectize({
            sortField: 'text'
        });
    }
});
```

Events/_form:

```
= simple_form_for @event do |f|
   = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success add-button"
   = f.input :starts_at, :minute_step => 15
  #tasks
    = f.simple_fields_for :attendances do |attendance|
      = render 'attendance_fields', f: attendance
    .links
      %p
      = link_to_add_association 'Add attendance', f, :attendances
```

_Attendance_fields:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.select :guest_id, Guest.all.map{|c| [c, c.id]}, {},class: 'selectize'
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove attendance", f
```

Any ideas? Please help

Comment: You need to use the callback, as shown in the answer you linked. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm really new to programming & don't really understand .js yet.. could you please  give me a hint on what to do/what to look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your code selects the items of class `.selectize` on the page and then calls the `selectize` function on them. However, this call is only run upon initial load of the page. When new items are added dynamically to the page, you will have to do that again. Cocoon raises events, to which you can listen, and when they happen, you get the piece of html that was inserted.

So you could do something like:

```
$('form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, addedItem) {
  $(addedItem).find('.selectize').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
  })
});
```

This means: everytime somewhere in the form the cocoon event is raised, we will apply the `.selectize` code.

More examples and information can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items).

Comment: Works great. Thank you, Nathan!